# The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly in BDC

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, business-data-catalog

I created a custom BCS connector to index external system results into SharePoint.

Now I am getting the following error while crawling the content source:

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Check permissions on the service .

Comment: Can you create an external list? If so, can the crawl account access the External List?